# Why the error message shows during imputation by using R package mice? error message: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, r-mice

I have a problem using the imputation function `mice()` in R package **mice** for the **sleep** data in the package **VIM**. The error message is  *$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors*.
The structure of the sleep data is:

```
> str(sleep)
'data.frame':   62 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ BodyWgt : num  6654 1 3.38 0.92 2547 ...
 $ BrainWgt: num  5712 6.6 44.5 5.7 4603 ...
 $ NonD    : num  NA 6.3 NA NA 2.1 9.1 15.8 5.2 10.9 8.3 ...
 $ Dream   : num  NA 2 NA NA 1.8 0.7 3.9 1 3.6 1.4 ...
 $ Sleep   : num  3.3 8.3 12.5 16.5 3.9 9.8 19.7 6.2 14.5 9.7 ...
 $ Span    : num  38.6 4.5 14 NA 69 27 19 30.4 28 50 ...
 $ Gest    : num  645 42 60 25 624 180 35 392 63 230 ...
 $ Pred    : int  3 3 1 5 3 4 1 4 1 1 ...
 $ Exp     : int  5 1 1 2 5 4 1 5 2 1 ...
 $ Danger  : int  3 3 1 3 4 4 1 4 1 1 ...
```

The error shows when I run

```
> mice(sleep)

 iter imp variable
  1   1  NonD  Dream  Sleep  Span  Gest
  1   2  NonD  Dream  Sleep  Span  Gest
  1   3  NonD  Dream  Sleep  Span  Gest
  1   4  NonD  Dream  Sleep  Span  Gest
  1   5  NonD  Dream  Sleep  Span  Gest
  2   1  NonD  Dream  Sleep  Span Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I'm using **R 4.0.2**, **mice_3.11.0** and **VIM_6.0.0**.

Does anyone know why this happens? Thanks a lot.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950  LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950 LC_NUMERIC=C                                
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] mvtnorm_1.1-0    glmnet_4.0       Matrix_1.2-18    boot_1.3-25      mice_3.11.0      MASS_7.3-51.6   
[7] VIM_6.0.0        colorspace_1.4-1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] shape_1.4.4       zoo_1.8-8         tidyselect_1.1.0  purrr_0.3.4       haven_2.2.0       lattice_0.20-41  
 [7] carData_3.0-4     vctrs_0.3.0       generics_0.0.2    rlang_0.4.6       e1071_1.7-3       pillar_1.4.4     
[13] foreign_0.8-80    glue_1.4.1        sp_1.4-2          readxl_1.3.1      foreach_1.5.0     lifecycle_0.2.0  
[19] robustbase_0.93-6 cellranger_1.1.0  zip_2.0.4         codetools_0.2-16  laeken_0.5.1      rio_0.5.16       
[25] forcats_0.5.0     lmtest_0.9-37     curl_4.3          class_7.3-17      vcd_1.4-7         DEoptimR_1.0-8   
[31] broom_0.5.6       Rcpp_1.0.4.6      backports_1.1.6   abind_1.4-5       ranger_0.12.1     hms_0.5.3        
[37] stringi_1.4.6     openxlsx_4.1.5    dplyr_0.8.5       tools_4.0.2       magrittr_1.5      tibble_3.0.1     
[43] crayon_1.3.4      car_3.0-8         tidyr_1.1.0       pkgconfig_2.0.3   ellipsis_0.3.1    data.table_1.12.8
[49] iterators_1.0.12  assertthat_0.2.1  R6_2.4.1          rpart_4.1-15      nnet_7.3-14       nlme_3.1-148     
[55] compiler_4.0.2
```

Comment: Hi, can't reproduce the issue running `data("sleep", package="VIM");mice::mice(sleep)`, please add `sessionInfo()` to question.

Comment: Already added `sessionInfo()` to the post.

Comment: Thanks, hard to tell though. How does the code of my previous comment run in a fresh R session?

Comment: The error still shows ... at the 1st iteration `iter imp variable`  `1   1  NonD  Dream  Sleep  SpanError: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. Any other library imported after "mice" somehow messes up with mice() functionality.

One solution is to important "mice" in the end after you have imported all the other libraries (including tidyverse) and then import mice in the end.

Comment: By ''imported" ,do you mean `library(mice)` ?  I tried in **R 4.0.3** library() for other packages first and mice in the end, but it still cannot work. Maybe some packages really mess up with mice at somewhere we don't know.